# What is the difference between HTTP Post URL with /post and without using Python requests module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-post, python-requests

I am using Python 2.7 with the requests module to send http post with parameters. I encountered a strange problem.

To do http post, it is just one line;

```
x = requests.post(URL, params)
```

I have no problem with the `params`. It is the `URL` that puzzled me.

Sometimes, this URL `http://hostname/path/post` works. Sometimes, I use `http://hostname/path` without the `/post` to get the HTTP post to work. I am puzzled why is this so. What is the difference between the two? Under what conditions do I use which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'http://hostname/path/post'` is a *path*.  You could in principle issue and HTTP GET request to that same path (although probably you wouldn't get anything meaningful back).

In general, you should look at the site's API documentation and post to the url that they say you should post to without adding anything extra to the url.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different concepts, url and HTTP method. You are confused by trying to mix them.

## url - an address you talk to

The url is addressing something on some server. If you get valid url, you can take it as a string, do not read in, and use it. Consider it to be a string.

If I would link it to a visiting your friend, url is address of a doors to come to.

## HTTP method (POST, GET, DELETE...)

There are multiple HTTP methods which differ in the way, how you talk to given url.

Linking it to visiting a friend, it would be the way, you try to make the doors open (use the bell, knock or use a hammer)